# How to add filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux

I need to do this to do filtration by counterparty, I know, that I need to add a such opportunity just in controller, to write a new nethod and a later to add it in full of filtration, but I don't know, what I must do.

In this file I need to add the filter itself, this code is written on the react.

filter.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Select                          from 'react-select';
import moment                          from 'moment';
import * as utils                      from '../../utils';

export default class RegistersFilter extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    filter: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    current: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleFilterChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { filter, current, handleFilterChange } = this.props;
    const monthsNames = moment.monthsShort();
    const options = {
      years: filter.years.map((year) => {
        return { value: year, label: year };
      }),
      months: monthsNames.map((monthName, index) => {
        return { value: index + 1, label: monthName };
      })
    }

    return(
      <div className="registers-filter">
        <Select
          name="years"
          className="registers-filter-select"
          onChange={handleFilterChange('year')}
          options={options.years}
          value={current.year}
        />
        <Select
          name="months"
          className="registers-filter-select"
          onChange={handleFilterChange('month')}
          options={options.months}
          value={current.month}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And in this file I need to add a method, this is ruby on rails.

registers.rb

```
class Register < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workspace
  belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :counterparty, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'Counterparty'
  belongs_to :sales_manager, class_name: 'Counterparty'

  validates :date, :value, :article_id, :workspace_id, presence: true
  validates :value, numericality: true

  scope :years, -> {
    distinct.pluck('cast(extract(year from date) as integer)')
            .sort { |a, b| b.to_i <=> a.to_i }
  }

  scope :extract_by_date, -> (props) {
    if props[:months].present?
      extract_by(:year, props[:years]).extract_by(:month, props[:months])
    else
      extract_by(:year, props[:years])
    end
  }

  scope :extract_by, -> (name, value) {
    return unless value.present?
    term = value.kind_of?(Array) ? 'IN (?)' : '= ?'
    where("cast(extract(#{name.to_s} from date) as integer) #{term}", value)
  }

  scope :by_page, -> (page) {
    if (page)
      per_page = 20
      offset(page.to_i * per_page).limit(per_page)
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is, how do I add filtering to counterparties, I do not know how to do this, here are two files in which you need to add the code that it has earned, there are already filters, but I still do not understand how to do it.